# How to properly import collada with python?

Tags: python

How do you properly import a collada file using the python api?

I have this [Blender URDF Visualizer](https://github.com/mcevoyandy/blender_urdf_visualizer) repo and want to be able to import either `stl` or `collada`. I import stl's just fine on [this line](https://github.com/mcevoyandy/blender_urdf_visualizer/blob/main/viewer/load_urdf.py#L269) and thought importing a collada would just be to change the import based on the extension:

```
if file_extension.lower == 'stl':
    bpy.ops.import_mesh.stl(filepath=mesh_path)
elif file_extension.lower == 'dae':
    bpy.ops.wm.collada_import(filepath=mesh_path, auto_connect = False, find_chains = False, fix_orientation = False)
else:
    print('ERROR: Expected stl or dae model')

new_obj = bpy.context.selected_objects[0]
new_obj.parent = new_link
```

and keep the rest of the code the same. However, testing with some example collada files from the [UR Description package](https://github.com/UniversalRobots/Universal_Robots_ROS2_Description), they come in empty through the python command, but as expected going through the GUI import option... not sure where the issue is and True/False for the options doesn't seem to change anything.

Any help getting pointed in the right direction would be appreciated.

[image]